# How to use setfacl within a Docker container?

Tags: permissions, docker

It seems like within the container the filesystem is mounted without 'acl', therefore 'setfacl' won't work. And it won't let me remount it either, and I can't even run 'df -h'.

I need setfacl because I make root own all the files from my websites, and I give the webserver user write permissions to only a few directories like cache, logs, etc.

What can I do?

Comment: Can someone help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037507/acl-issue-with-xfs-as-backing-filesystem-with-overlay2-driver-docker?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The good news is that Docker supports ACLs.

In early releases Docker used a filesystem named AUFS which didn't support  them.
You could tell Docker to use Device Mapper (LVM) for its storage, by starting your Docker daemon with the appropriate option:

```
docker -d --storage-driver=devicemapper --daemon=true
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/165AARba2Bk

and then you were able to use `setfacl` in your containers.

Any reasonably recent release or Docker now uses the `overlay2` storage driver, which supports that out of the box.
To check what is your storage driver:

`docker info | grep Storage`

`df -h` doesn't work for a different and unrelated reason : it relies on `/etc/mtab`, not present in your case. In your container, create a link from `procfs`, that will solve this problem:

```
ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Comment: Interesting! But aren't there any downsides in switching to LVM? Every time I read about the benefits of Docker it mentioned AUFS, though I didn't fully understand it. Anyway, in the source you linked it says something I was thinking about and was going to try next: use a volume, which I needed anyway in the same place to share the files. I'm just not sure how this would work, because when I'm running these commands I'm in the Dockerfile so I don't have my volumes yet, because I add them when I start the cointainer daemon after building the image.

Comment: AUFS and LVM (dm-thin) are very different implementations, that's a vast topic. But you shouldn't see any functional difference after switching your Docker daemon to it. Downside : was less stable, but they claim this has improved a lot with 0.9 and 0.9.1 releases. Also, note that volumes also accept bind mounts : you can bind an existing directory on the host to the container, I guess that would allow you to "see" the same content at image building time.

Comment: From the docs: "Note that [bind mount] is not available from a Dockerfile due the portability and sharing purpose of it". Changing the storage-driver seems good, I found the options can be easily modified in /etc/default/docker. But I need to rebuild all the images, so while I was doing that I realized something: I'm using containers! Meaning I don't need to worry about permissions as much as before, so for now I will just chown/chmod the folders I want to be writable by the webserver user, no need to use setfacl. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any idea if `Overlay2` supports `ACL`?

Comment: This blogpost https://tech.kaleo.blog/post/use-setfacl-within-docker/ says overlay2 supports though I couldn't get any sucess to set up acl on alpine with overlay2.

Comment: For posterity, yes @MohammedNoureldin , `overlay2` supports `setfacl` just fine. If you're on an older system, you may have to upgrade to a newer version of docker, and may also have to [explicitly tell it to use overlay2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver).