# symfony docker permission problems for cache files

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose

I have a symfony setup for docker with docker-compose which is working well except when i run *cache:clear* from console, the webserver cant access the files.

I can circumvent the permission problem by uncommenting *umask(0000);* in console and web/app_dev.php but i would like to run symfony as recommended.

What i do is spin up the containers `docker-compose up`
Then i enter the container. The container contains the apache, php and the code via a data volume.

```
docker exec -i -t apache_1 /bin/bash
```

Apparently i am logged in as root then and when i run

```
app/console cache:clear
```

all files in cache belong to user root. www-data as webserver user now cant access the files anymore.

I also can circumvent this by logging in as www-data then the files generated by the cache:clear belong to www-data and the webserver can access them.

```
docker exec -u www-data -i -t apache_1 /bin/bash
```

But this has the downside that i dont land in bash but in */usr/sbin/nologin* and dont have things like bash_history and so on.

Searching around i found this as part of the Dockerfile to solve the permission issue but it as no effect for me.

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

If i understand correct this switches the user 1000 to www-data, but as i am root when i login to the container this does not work, i assume.

So why am i *root* when i login to the container and how is this *usermod* suppose to work?

the docker-compose.yml:

```
proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  ports:
    - "80:80"
elastic:
  build: docker/elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  volumes:
    - data/elasticsearch:/usr/local/elasticsearch/data
apache:
  build: docker/apachephp
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.dev
  volumes:
    - ./code:/var/www/app
    - ./dotfiles/.bash_history:/.bash_history
    - ./logs:/var/www/app/app/logs
  links:
    - elastic
  expose:
    - "80"
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

Comment: im afraid chmod +a is not available in ubuntu and setfacl is not working with a default docker setup

Comment: can you add your docker-compose.yml please ?

Comment: docker-compose.yml is added

Comment: But `setfacl` is available. You can also run CLI as webserver user. You should do necessary things to run Symfony, or you'll stay with you problem.

Comment: can you post an example of a Dockerfile with setfacl, i keep getting "setfacl: var: No such file or directory"

Comment: Well the files in your cache directory shouldn't be chown to root, it should be to your host user. Did you try to simply delete everything in the cache dir and then access your app or run any console command ? They should be written as www-data for the first time

Comment: @Snroki why should they belong to the host? when i run cache:clear inside the container they belong to the user inside the container. if i run web first on an empty cache dir they are from www-data, thats correct.

Comment: the cache files would belong to the host if i run cache:clear on the host, then `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data` would make sense, i guess

Comment: that's true, it depends how you initiated your project (i did it on my host so that's why). I actually created an alias for clear/warmup the cache in the container and run chown -R www-data:www-data on the cache directory this way i'm sure to always have the right. Btw (just in case) the uid 1000 will only work if your host user was the first user created (else your uid will be 1001, 1002 or whatever)

Comment: ok things get clearer :) creating aliases would be a way, even though it seems a bit edgy and would bypass symfony advices

Comment: regarding setfacl: i suppose this cant be run in a Dockerfile but must be run after the container is up, any suggestions on how to do this automatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22715283/3675759

Comment: yes i saw this, it means setfacl cant be run on a default docker setup. Its possible, yes, by changing the storage-driver but i would rather avoid this because i have other docker projects that would be affected as well.

Comment: on mac default user id is 501, so that would be `RUN usermod -u 501 www-data` in the webserver Dockerfile. To be sure run `id -u` on your host system. I was wondering how to set this dynamically when using docker-compose...

Comment: If anybody has the issue, try to `chgrp www-data /tmp/cache` and to `chmod -R ug+rwX /tmp/cache`, in your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd think changing `www-data`s userid to your host-user's id is a good solution, as permissions for the host user are fairly easy to setup.

```
#change www-data`s UID inside a Dockerfile
RUN usermod -u [USERID] www-data
```

user id 1000 is the default for most linux systems afaik... 501 on mac
you can run `id -u` on the host system to find out.

You could then log into the container to run symfony commands as www-data

`docker exec -it -u www-data [CONTAINER] bash`

I was wondering how you could set the userid dynamically on container build.
I guess  passing it via `--build-arg` to docker-compose would be the way

```
docker-compose build --build-arg USERID=$(id -u)
```

...but haven't managed to access that var in the Dockerfile yet.

Comment: on my standard Docker LAMP setup:

root: 0
www-data: 33
ubuntu: 1000

Comment: thanks, entering the container s bash as www-data works. For all others, all our experience regarding problems like this went into https://github.com/nerdpress-org/docker-sf3 , hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Max's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36493746/1903743)

Note that these ideas can be used for non-symfony apps too.

Dockerfile:

```
# 1000 is default, in case --build-arg is not passed with the build command.
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG GROUP_ID=1000
ARG HOME_DIR=/home/www-data
# Change user ID & group ID & home directory & shell of www-data user.
# We change home dir because some custom commands may use home dir
# for caching (like composer, npm or yarn) or for another reason.
RUN mkdir ${HOME_DIR} \
    && chown -R ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} ${HOME_DIR} \
    && usermod --uid ${USER_ID} --home ${HOME_DIR} --shell /bin/bash www-data \
    && groupmod --gid ${GROUP_ID} www-data
```

And if you want to run commands as www-data user in Dockerfile/ENTRYPOINT/CMD etc. you can use `su` like this:

```
su - www-data -c "cd /var/www/html && composer install && npm install && node_modules/.bin/encore dev --watch &"
```

Build command:

```
# $(id -u) gets the current user's ID and $(id -g) gets the current user's group ID.
# If you want to use another ID go ahead and replace them.
docker-compose build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g)
# or
docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g) .
```