# Enable acl on docker alpine image

Tags: docker, acl, alpine-linux

I don't find a sample docker image based on **alpine** which automatically install the acl package and enable it on the main mount point /

I have found the  manual procedure for Ubuntu:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs
which I guess would work for alpine too, but no acl-ready alpine docker image.

Could you please help me about this ?

UPDATE:
I found this link which specify using the --storage-driver=devicemapper option:
[How to use setfacl within a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714885/how-to-use-setfacl-within-a-docker-container)
I have to check the drawback

Thanks and regards,
Christophe

Comment: Did you get a success in it ? I am also looking for the same but in vain.

Answer (score 6):

To install acl on alpine you have to run `apk add acl` and see if it is working on your case. See all available commands using `setfacl --help`.

E.g `setfacl -m u:deploy:rw ~/test`

However in my case acl work in only named volume but not in bind mounted volume. I am unsure about the proper --storage-driver. In my case overlay2 work fine. So try it out and feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding acl package only enables you to query ACL's, but it won't make container use them, thus all the "access denied" issues remain.

Comment: `setfacl` works for me on _PHP:8-fpm-alpine_ to add rights as it is described on https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#installing-lexikjwtauthenticationbundle